# cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.1.2:wsdl2java failed:Illegal character in opaque part at index 2

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, wsdl2java

I'm unable to use cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin to generate required sources from WSDL due to the following exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.1.2:wsdl2java (generate-sources) on project innoclient: Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.1.2:wsdl2java failed: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\WORK\BAG\WS\POC\innoclient/src/main/wsdl/mywsdl.wsdl -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.1.2:wsdl2java (generate-sources) on project innoclient: Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.1.2:wsdl2java failed: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\WORK\WS\POC\src/main/wsdl/mywsdl.wsdl
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.1.2:wsdl2java failed: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\WORK\WS\POC\src/main/wsdl/mywsdl.wsdl
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:143)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\WORK\WS\POC\src/main/wsdl/mywsdl.wsdl
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:859)
        at java.net.URI.resolve(URI.java:1043)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.WSDL2JavaMojo.processWsdl(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:278)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.WSDL2JavaMojo.execute(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:228)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\WORK\WS\POC\src/main/wsdl/mywsdl.wsdl
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3002)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3039)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:595)
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:857)
        ... 24 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

And the definition part of my WSDL looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://AcmeToolKit.com/"
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://AcmeToolKit.com/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
```

Any pointers to solve this issue would be helpful.

Thanks and Regards,
San

Comment: Is it possible that your wsdl file starts with a linefeed or perhaps a space? I believe <?xml must start in position 1,1.

Comment: just verified that it exactly starts at 1,1

Comment: In my case it was a stupid path problem, i had ../META_INF/mywsdl.wsdl instead of ../META-INF/mywsdl.wsdl

Comment: I too have this issue @kallada , you resolved this ?

Answer (score 10):

The issue seems to be in the path itself.
"C:\WORK\WS\POC\src/main/wsdl/mywsdl.wsdl" is not a valid IRI - that is that the exception is about, not the content of the file it self.

If you have something like

```
<bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/binding.xml</bindingFile>
```

in your pom.xml file, just change it to:

```
<bindingFile>./src/main/resources/binding.xml</bindingFile>
```

may not be the best, but get the job done.